# Text positioning in 2nd VC

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text, uitextview

I have set the notifications to keep the text in textView above the keyboard. My problem is, when I select the table view cell to display my text in the next VC, that the text appears few lines below the top and only after I start editing (keyboard shows up) and than swipe to dismiss the keyboard, text repositions itself at the top, where it should be.How can I force the text to be at the top as soon as VC displays its content, before the keyboard appears? Thanks.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "adjustForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "adjustForKeyboard:", name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)


    storyTextView.text = passedText
    title = passedTitle

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

func adjustForKeyboard(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIKeyboardWillHideNotification {
        storyTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }else {
        storyTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }

    storyTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = storyTextView.contentInset

    let selectedRange = storyTextView.selectedRange
    storyTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    storyTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Comment: I did manage to move it to the top by adding storyTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero in viewDidAppear(), but there is a delay. Text first appears below and then moves up. Putting the above in viewDidLoad(), didn't make any difference.

Comment: Guess I solved it... viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear did the trick :)

Comment: Hmmm... The problem still persists when the device is rotated to landscape mode. Any ideas how to tackle this one? It's beyond my pay grade :) Im guessing it has to do with constraints, but don't know how to approach the problem.